# The current version of Node (16.4.1) is not supported by Angular.How to completely get rid of a software in mac?

Tags: node.js, angular

I installed node(16.4.1) but it's not supporting Angular! I uninstalled it but it's still present with version 16! How to get rid of this version completely? I'm new to Angular.I used CLI in this case.

Comment: I don't see anything in your post that backs up your claim, so you'll want to start with that. But only after you checked Angular's issue tracker to see if this is a known issue, because if it is, there was no reason to post here.

Comment: Sorry.I'm looking for a solution & no given solution worked for me.I'm stuck. And how will i start with that?

Comment: In that case you will want to [make sure to mention what you already found/tried in your post](/help/how-to-ask) so that folks understand what you already know, rather than assuming you didn't search for anything and just posted to SO because it was convenient. If you've already put in the effort, make sure folks know hat you did, so they don't ask you to do things or check things you've already done or checked.

Comment: As for issues on the Angular projects, https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20796 and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/42076 exist, which of the various things people talk about in those threads did you already try (and remember: explain that in your post, not in a comment), and what did that result in (bearing in mind that the current version of Angular supports all current versions of Node: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/12.2.6/package.json#L11 clearly shows 12.2.6 supports Node LTS v12, as well as all versions 14 and up, so which version of Angular are you using?)

Answer (score -1):

its okay to ask such questions as a beginner
here is the solution to your problem
[How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)
no worries i would suggest you to learn how to google your answer like a  expert developer this will help you very much in your development career.

Comment: Except your answer does not address the _actual_ problem: Angular works just fine, 12.2.6 works with all in-support versions of Node, and uninstalling Node is not a solution of any sort here.